(Lack of) Relationship Between Neyman Orthogonality and Sobolev Norm
I've been reading about double/debiased/Neyman ML estimators as described in Chernozhukov et al. 2018. They use Neyman orthogonality to debias, which is stated here as
$$
\partial_\eta E\psi(W; \theta_0, \eta)|_{\eta_0 = \eta} = 0
$$
in contrast to the traditional moment condition $E\psi(W; \theta_0, \eta_0) = 0$. $\psi$ is a score function, $W = (D,X,Y)$, $\eta_0$ is the population nuisance function, and $\theta_0$ is the population parameter of interest.
When I read this condition, it seemed similar to a sobolev norm minimization problem: intuitively, adding a first derivative-based term to a minimization problem that's closely related to $L_2$ projection/norm problems would imply something related to $W_{1,2}$ norm/minimization problems. However, this isn't discussed at all in any of the papers I read even when the authors are using Sobolev methods elsewhere.
I suspect that my confusion is due to a misunderstanding of the Neyman orthogonality on my end, or that the derivative is wrt a function. They authors also specify that they use the Gateaux derivative, which I'm unfamiliar with. What characteristic of Neyman orthogonality makes Sobolev approaches unhelpful?
